# First click doesn't trigger an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, click

I want to trigger click event on input after clicking on certain div ('.checker'). In other words clicking on '.checker' simulates click event on checkbox, checking it remotely.

The code I wrote works, but click triggers only after the second click, at the first fails. This happens not even to the '.checker' but also to checkbox.

All this HTML below is wrapped in jquery collapse menu. After clicking on 'h3' '.sub-tree-wrap' collapses. The 'e.stopPropagation' is for prevent bubbling, which cause menu collapse.

The jquery uniform works that: clicking on input(checkbox) bubbles and this toggles class on span and div('.checker') in '.control_multi' - http://uniformjs.com/

On jsfiddle it works, but without jquery unform - http://jsfiddle.net/mciastek/PQP9S/3/ (thx Mark S)

What's important, I can manipulate HTML only by Javascript / jQuery.

HTML

```
<h3><div class='checker'></div></h3>
  <div class='sub-tree-wrap'>
    <div></div>
      <div class='control_multi'>
        <div>
          <span>
            <div class='checker'>
              <span>
                <input type='checkbox'>
              </span>
            </div>
         </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
   $('h3 > .checker').click(function(e){
            // prevent list collapse after click
            e.stopPropagation();
            $this = $(this);
            // if has control_open or checkbox is disabled don't run multiple checking
            var subTree = $this.parent().next();
            if( (!subTree.hasClass('has-open')) && !($this.hasClass('disabled')) ) {
                var inputCheck = $this.parent().next().find('.control_multi').find('input:checkbox')
                inputCheck.trigger('click');
            }
            // toggle class .checked after click
            $this.children('span').toggleClass('checked');
        });
```

Comment: Could you reproduce it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: You have a class name starting with dot `.checker` so you jquery selector will not work. Also do not put block elements (div) in inline elements (span).

Comment: `$this` is set up as a global variable, is this your intention?

Comment: My mistake. The input has checkbox type not class. But in jsfiddle it works http://jsfiddle.net/mciastek/PQP9S/3/ (thx Mark S). The problem is the checkboxes are styled with jQuery uniform http://uniformjs.com/. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: After some research I'm nearly 100% sure that the problem is jquery uniform and it's event click call. Does anyone knows how to change it / modify to prevent breaking my code?

Comment: The problem was solved by adding '$.uniform.update', which updates input classes due to class manipulation in my script. Check http://uniformjs.com/#docs

Answer (score 0):

Since `'.checkbox'` is an `<input>` element, use trigger ['focus'](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

```
$('h3 > .checker').click(function(e){
        // prevent list collapse after click
        e.stopPropagation();
        $this = $(this);
        // if has control_open or checkbox is disabled don't run multiple checking
        var subTree = $this.parent().next();
        if( (!subTree.hasClass('has-open')) && !($this.hasClass('disabled')) ) {
            var inputCheck = subTree.find('.control_multi .checkbox')
            inputCheck.trigger('focus');
        }
        // toggle class .checked after click
        $this.children('span').toggleClass('checked');
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/PQP9S/)